# Convert Ubuntu 13.04 to Mac theme error

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, software-installation, themes, mac

I'm following [this tutorial](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-make-ubuntu-12-04-look-like-mac-os-lion) and also [this YouTube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpENgOt0_JI).

On executing this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mac-os-lion-theme mac-os-lion-cursors mac-os-lion-icons
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done 
E: Unable to locate package mac-os-lion-theme 
E: Unable to locate package mac-os-lion-cursors 
E: Unable to locate package mac-os-lion-icons
```

Any Idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but solved it by substituting the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mac-icons-noobslab
sudo apt-get install mac-ithemes-noobslab
```

for the **Cursors**,  use:

```
wget -O mac-cursors.zip http://ubuntuone.com/05qtKEgDaFQ1V1TzNvoub5
sudo unzip mac-cursors.zip -d /usr/share/icons/ && rm mac-cursors.zip
cd /usr/share/icons/mac-cursors
sudo chmod +x install-mac-cursors.sh uninstall-mac-cursors.sh
./install-mac-cursors.sh
```

In fact they look better than our old method. 
    for further details:

[TechyGiene.com](http://techygiene.com/install-mac-os-x-lion-theme-on-ubuntu-13-0412-1012-04/)

Answer (score 0):

Did the repository get added?  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes` needs a `sudo apt-get update` first - you can't forget that.  You can verify that the repository was added with `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d`, which will show all of the non-standard repositories available.

Comment: It is showing there two things on ls /etc/apt...    cairo-dock-team-ppa-raring.list       noobslab-themes-raring.list
cairo-dock-team-ppa-raring.list.save  noobslab-themes-raring.list.save

Comment: BTW Still getting the same error.